# Click on TextView inside inflated Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have an inflated Linear Layout that contains 2 TextViews inside it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ll_borders"
    android:tag="m"
    android:text="m" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_q"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ll_borders"
    android:tag="q"
    android:text="q" />
</LinearLayout>
```

All i want is that when this Linear Layout is inflated then i want to get the only `TEXTVIEW` on which i click. For example if i click on "`tv_m`" then it shall only return me the text of `tv_m`.
May b its simple but i am not getting a way to it.  So i need help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After inflating the layout get the textview objects as below

```
LinearLayout layout = inflater.inflate(<your layout name>, null);
TextView textView1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_m));
TextView textView2 = layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_q));
String selectedText;
textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             selectedText = textView1.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Similarly you can put listener for textView2 also. The selectedText will be the final string which you want.

Comment: i was making a mistake...i also set onClick listener to the inflated view and because of that it was not getting click of the textView inside it..
Anyways i have done now...Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up on click listeners for the text views.  Then when one is clicked, it will call a function in your code passing it the view that was touched.  Then you can call getText on it.

Comment: I had set onClick on the view then from that view i had got textView like this:
TextView m = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tv_m);

now i had to set onClick on that "m"  ??

Comment: i was making a mistake...i also set onClick listener to the inflated view and because of that it was not getting click of the textView inside it.. Anyways i have done now...Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

here is the code just check this out :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout lt = (LinearLayout) findViewById( R.id.linearLayout );
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(your xml to be inflate, null, false);
    lt.addView(view);

    TextView tv_m = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.tv_m);
    TextView tv_l = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.tv_l);

   tv_m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
   @Override         
    public void onClick(View v) {     

       tv_m.getText(); // to get the value written on text view
       }      }); 
}
```

Comment: i was making a mistake...i also set onClick listener to the inflated view and because of that it was not getting click of the textView inside it..
Anyways i have done now...Thanks :)